# Count pattern with random characters

Tags: r, regex, string

I would like to count multiple patterns, but including * (any character) in them.
Here is an example search for: `Y*Y`, `YY*` and `X*X` simultaneously

```
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  V2 = c("XXYYYYY", "XXYYXX" , "XYXXYX", "XYYXYX")
  )
```

And here is my try:

```
library(stringr)
df$V3 <- str_count(df$V2, "Y+Y+")
df$V4 <- str_count(df$V2, "YY+")
df$V5 <- str_count(df$V2, "X+X+")
```

I am not sure how to specify a random character in a string and how to count two or more patterns at once.

Expected output:

```
V1      V2 V3 V4 V5
A XXYYYYY  1  1  1
B  XXYYXX  1  1  2
C  XYXXYX  2  0  3
D  XYYXYX  2  1  3
```

Comment: The wildcards , `*` matches for all characters  (what you call random) and `|` could be used to separate multiple patterns `pattern1 | pattern2`

Comment: and what can you recommend for choosing a character from a pool of characters e.g. only X, Y or Z, in other words * can either be X or Y, or Z

Comment: @Osssan `*` doesn't mean "any character" but that the previous character appears "zero or more times". `.` means "any character"

Comment: you can try `str_count(V2, "Y([^Y]|$)"); str_count(V2, "YY+([^Y]|$)"); str_count(V2, "X([^X]|$)")`

Comment: not sure how to use `|` within str_count
`str_count(df$V2, ("Y*Y+") | ("YY+") | ("X*X+"))`, this is not the way to go

Comment: see my comment above your last one to get `V3`, `V4` and `V5` respectively

Comment: If you have a list of characters CharList and want to choose one at random,  just use `sample(CharList, 1)`